# Justify inner Flexbox items across full width of flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a Flexbox in use for header navigation, the logo is aligned to the left and the ul items are aligned to the right as in a traditional style. Both the logo and the navigation links are flex items within a full width Flexbox, and I have given them both flex: 50%. The navigation links section is also a Flexbox (an inner Flexbox) to prevent the menu from stacking and instead behaving in a better responsive manner.

When I apply justify-content to that inner Flexbox, there is no change to the links, as if there is an overriding style or the property does not work on an inner text box. I should like the navigation links to equally divide themselves among the 50% of the screen width.

I've toyed with placing flex: auto on the items but can't keep it within the current layout by doing that, and I've tried fiddling with inline elements to see if I can remove any overriding property, but no cigar.

```css
#nav {
    display: flex;
    flex: 50%;
    align-items: center;
}

#logo {
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
}

#links {
    margin-left: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#links a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
 <img id="logo" src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-placeholder-png.png"/>
 <ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#">Link1<a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link2<a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link3<a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link4<a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: inspect the element to see that the use of margin will make the element shrink-to-fit so there is no space to distribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Important changes I made were to set the width of the `#links` `<ul>` to 50% and add `justify-content: space-between` to the container `#nav` wrapper. A few other style changes to the `ul` so it doesnt have default margin and padding and I think it is behaving as you are expecting now..

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#logo {
  width: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

#links {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#links a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
 <img id="logo" src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-placeholder-png.png"/>
 <ul id="links">
  <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `flex: 50%;` CSS deceleration. It's not at proper place. I have re-write the html to use it properly and fixed the CSS according.

Here is the Modified CSS

```css
 #nav {
            display: flex;
            background: #eee;
        }

        #nav>#logo,
        #nav>#links {
            flex: 50%;
        }
        #logo img {
            width: 50px;
            height: auto;
        }

        #links {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #links a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

```html
 <nav id="nav">
        <div id="logo"><img src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/logo-placeholder-png.png" /> </div>
        <ul id="links">
            <li><a href="#">Link1<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link4<a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Also the code available at codepen https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/jRjZxB/